# Replace previously replaced word in string with RegExp

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which adds a string to an array:

```
sql = new Array();

query = "SELECT * FROM specimen";

$('#keyword').change(function(){

filter = " MATCH(clinical_history) AGAINST ('_KEYWORD_' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH(specimen) AGAINST ('_KEYWORD_' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH(macroscopic) AGAINST ('_KEYWORD_' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH(microscopic) AGAINST ('_KEYWORD_' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH(conclusion) AGAINST ('_KEYWORD_' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH(comment) AGAINST ('_KEYWORD_' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";

sql.push(filter);

});
```

Then I'm replacing the `_KEYWORD_` placeholder in the above string with the value of an input field:

```
$('#search_container').on('click', '#search_btn', function(){

keyword = $('#keyword_field').val();

var regExp = new RegExp('_KEYWORD_', 'g');    
$.each(sql, function(index, value) {
    sql[index] = value.replace(regExp, keyword);


if(sql != ''){
query += " WHERE " + sql.join('  AND ');
}

});
```

Now that works fine once, but not when the the `_KEYWORD_` place holder has been replaced by the input value.  What I need to do is to determine the last input value and use that in the replace code.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Also this can cause issues, if the keyword given is 'MATCH', then when you try to replace it again, the MATCH in other part of the string will get replaced

Comment: Yep, the order was pasted in wrong, now updated in OP.

Comment: The placeholder underscoreKEYWORDunderscore in the MATCH query should, and is, being changed to the same value, which is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last input value may not be unique in the string.  It could well be the same as other words that are part of the sql query.  Trying to do it that way is both difficult and not guaranteed to be 100% reliable.

I would suggest that you just save the original template string separately before any replacements have been made so you always have that original.  Then, you can do the replace the same way every time.  Simple and 100% reliable.

One way to structure this would be to make each element of your sql Array be an object that has two properties, the template string and the converted/replaced string.  Then, you will always have both.

```
var sql = [];

$('#keyword').change(function(){
    var obj = {};
    obj.filter = " MATCH(clinical_history) AGAINST ('_KEYWORD_' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH(specimen) AGAINST ('_KEYWORD_' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH(macroscopic) AGAINST ('_KEYWORD_' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH(microscopic) AGAINST ('_KEYWORD_' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH(conclusion) AGAINST ('_KEYWORD_' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH(comment) AGAINST ('_KEYWORD_' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
    sql.push(obj);
});

$('#search_container').on('click', '#search_btn', function(){
    var keyword = $('#keyword_field').val();
    var regExp = new RegExp('_KEYWORD_', 'g');    
    $.each(sql, function(index, value) {
        // store the replacement string as the .replaced property
        // so the .filter property remains unchanged and can be used 
        // again in the future
        sql[index].replaced = sql[index].filter.replace(regExp, keyword);
    });

    if (sql.length) {
        var q = $.map(sql, function(elem) {
            return elem.replaced;
        });
        query += " WHERE " + q.join('  AND ');
    }
});
```

Comment: That code returmns SELECT * FROM specimen WHERE [object Object]

Comment: I've added a bit more code to th OP to make it clearer what I'm doing

Comment: @PeterBrowne - are you 100% sure you implemented the code I suggested and then you use the `sql[index].replaced` version of the string anywhere you want the actual query?  `[object Object]` makes me think you're referencing an object instead of a property on that object.

Comment: @PeterBrowne - Your other code wasn't using the new array format properly.  I updated my code to include the new part you've added to your question.  The important thing to realize here is that `sql` is an array of objects.  It's not an array of strings.  You can't just `.join()` the array of objects like you were.

Comment: Yep, that last bit did the trick.  Many thanks for your expertise!